# creating new javax.xml.ws.Service not returns

Tags: web-services, jboss

I am having a strange problem occuring somtimes from a specific machine (windows 2003).

I am trying to create a new `javax.xml.ws.Service` instance with host and qname as parameters.

```
service = new SomeService(url, qName);
```

the service creation (ONLY SOMETIMES!) never returns.
While the creation is stucked on my prod machine, development machines are working OK.

I am running with Java 5 on jboss 4.2.3

Any suggestions? I'm pretty puzzled.

Comment: Without knowing what SomeService is, we can't help you.

Comment: The service SomeService extends javax.xml.ws.Service.

Comment: That's not what I asked.